# Hide menu on scroll down and show on scroll up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sticky

I made this snippet code to hide menu on scroll down and show on scroll up but I have some issues, when I scroll to top the menu still have fixed position, how I can resolve this problem, Thanks! 
JAVSCRIPT :

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 500) {
        $('.mainmenu').addClass('nav-down');
    }
});

// Hide Header on on scroll down
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $('.mainmenu').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event){
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if (didScroll) {
        hasScrolled();
        didScroll = false;
    }
}, 500);

function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    // Make sure they scroll more than delta
    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
        return;

    // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
    // This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
        // Scroll Down
        $('.mainmenu').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
    } else {
        // Scroll Up
        if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
            $('.mainmenu').removeClass('nav-up');
        }
    }

    lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

CSS :

```
.mainmenu {
    background: #222;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.nav-down{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
    width: 100%;
}
.nav-up {
    top: -50px;
}
```

Demo : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uikithemes/s6mLJ/3066/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested it and it works fine!!

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
if ($(window).scrollTop() > 500) {
    $('.mainmenu').addClass('nav-down');
}
else
{
    $('.mainmenu').removeClass('nav-down');
}
});
```

Answer (score 5):

To you first listener, just add an else statement as follows:

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function () {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 150)
        $('.mainmenu').addClass('nav-down');
    else
        $('.mainmenu').removeClass('nav-down');
});
```

Also note that you don't need a `setInterval()` for the second listener, see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/leofcx/nL4p4fre/2/)

Comment: Thank you so much, the menu is working :) but can I add transition when the menu disappear like when the menu appearing, because when I scroll down the menu hide directly.

Comment: You have to apply the transition to `.mainmenu` , not to the class that is added - see my answer;)

Answer (score 0):

Add an else to your scrollTop with a removeClass and you should be fine, I tested it and it works. Here

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
if ($(window).scrollTop() > 500) {
    $('.mainmenu').addClass('nav-down');
}
else
{
    $('.mainmenu').removeClass('nav-down');
}
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the menu is working :) but can I add transition when the menu disappear like when the menu appearing, because when I scroll down the menu hide directly.

Answer (score 0):

Detect nav direction with a variable

```
var lastscrolltop=0;
jQuery(window).bind('scroll', function () {
        if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() > lastscrolltop)
            jQuery('.mainmenu').addClass('nav-up');
        else
            jQuery('.mainmenu').removeClass('nav-up');
        lastscrolltop=jQuery(window).scrollTop();
});
```

and use css transition for a smooth show/hide

```
.mainmenu {
    transition:all 0.5s ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your way is too much complicated.
You can hide the menu on scroll with a simple transition using jQuery `.fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()`, without the need for css.

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;

$(window).scroll(function(event){

   var st = $(this).scrollTop();

   if (st > lastScrollTop){
      $('.mainmenu').fadeOut('fast');
   } else {
      $('.mainmenu').fadeIn('fast');
   }

lastScrollTop = st;

});
```